# minimalistic mailserver running on centos

Tags: email, centos

I'm trying to make my work/life a bit easier, with "developing" a workflow management tool. My problem is setting a proper test environment, because I'm not a sys admin.

The workflow management tool should send e-mails on certain events. I have a standalone centOS server were my tool is running. For every user i created a local user on this machine. I found lots of manuals/howtos on setting up a mail server, but they did not match my needs.

I want a very minimalistic setup. I want to have a "post box" for the local users on the centOS server, which they can query with their favorite mail client (outlook, k-mail, evolution, thunderbird, ...) from their clients. It should only be possible to put mails into these local post boxes, and to read them via smtp from the user's computer. I explicitly don't want this "mail server" to send/forward mails to the (inter)net, or to accept mails form the (inter)net.

I searched a lot, but nothing matched my needs. Can you provide me some keywords to search for?

Yours

Pete

Answer (score 0):

You can take postfix combined with dovecot.
In postfix main.cf enter somsthing like:
*myhostname = example.com*

Comment: I'll give it a try as soon as posible